# Set another bend point for a tikz edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, edge

On the left hand side you can see a tikz graph with a bend edge that is not placed really optimal. Is there a way to place the edge somewhat similar to the illustration on the right hand side.

[image]
[image]

Here's the code for the image on the left:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % nodes
    \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node (B) at (-1,1) {B};
    \node (C) at (-1,3) {C};
    \node (D) at (0,3.5) {D};
    \node (E) at (0,5) {E};
    \node (F) at (-1,4.5) {F};

    % just for illustration
    \node (here would be a lot more) at (0.5,2) {...};

    % draw edges 
    \draw[->]
        (A) edge (B) 
        (B) edge (C)
        (C) edge (D) edge (F)
        (D) edge (E)
        (F) edge (E);

    % weird edge that should be fixed
    \draw[->]
        (A) edge[bend left=130] node[midway,above, sloped] {FIX ME} (F);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Just add another point.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % nodes
    \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node (B) at (-1,1) {B};
    \node (C) at (-1,3) {C};
    \node (D) at (0,3.5) {D};
    \node (E) at (0,5) {E};
    \node (F) at (-1,4.5) {F};

    % just for illustration
    \node (here would be a lot more) at (0.5,2) {...};

    % draw edges 
    \draw[->]
        (A) edge (B) 
        (B) edge (C)
        (C) edge (D) edge (F)
        (D) edge (E)
        (F) edge (E);

    % weird edge that should be fixed
    \draw[->]
        (A) to[out=-110,in=-60]++ (-2,0) to[out=120,in=150] 
        node[pos=0.4,above, sloped] {FIX ME} (F);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, the text would look nicer if you used `decorations.text`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % nodes
    \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \node (B) at (-1,1) {B};
    \node (C) at (-1,3) {C};
    \node (D) at (0,3.5) {D};
    \node (E) at (0,5) {E};
    \node (F) at (-1,4.5) {F};

    % just for illustration
    \node (here would be a lot more) at (0.5,2) {...};

    % draw edges 
    \draw[->]
        (A) edge (B) 
        (B) edge (C)
        (C) edge (D) edge (F)
        (D) edge (E)
        (F) edge (E);

    % weird edge that should be fixed
    \draw[<-,postaction={decoration={text along path, text={FIX ME},text
    align={center},raise=0.2cm},decorate}] (F) to[out=-150,in=150]
    ([xshift=-1em]F|-A) to[out=-30,in=-150] (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ty for your answer. :) Would you be able to provide some more information how this syntax works/is interpreted so that I can generalize the solution to other problems?

Comment: For clarification: I guess I see how you chain points together but I don't understand why the start point is placed right of A instead of at it's exact location. Or at least this is the case when I set the first in and out to 0. And also how you figured out the right values that it looks smooth. Trying? Or, is there some logic behind this?

Comment: @plauer The result is smooth if in a sequence of `to` paths the `in`s and the subsequent `out`s differ by `180`. So in `(A) to[out=-110,in=-60]++ (-2,0) to[out=120,in=150]` we have `in=-60` and the subsequent `out=120`, so the result has no kink.